# Reverse Proxying URL in the format <hostip>:<port>/<path>

Tags: reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have setup a home NAS/Server and I started using Nginx Proxy Manager (on same server) to use HTTPS on my local network. I am able to reverse proxy simple urls `192.168.88.254:19943` to subdomain 'docker.mydomain.com'. I have some application which I am accessing using URL like `https://192.168.88.254:55664/apps/photogallery/#/timeline` and `https://192.168.88.254:55664/apps/soundsgood/` , here 55664 is my HTTPS port. I am not able to reverse proxy these URLS. I am very new to Reverse Proxy and Setting up servers in general.

Thank you very much for any pointer or suggestion!